# Hostname for fetch in serverside component with NextJS13 on Vercel

Tags: next.js, next.js13

When using `fetch` in an server side component on NextJS13, code is written as follows:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test")
```

This endpoint (e.g., http..../test) varies on deployed environment. For example, this example is deployed on locally, but when deployed to certain branch, the host name should be something like `your-pj-and-git-branch.verce.app`.

So, the problem is that the code above should be rewritten depending on which environment it is deployed.

How can I switch the host for `fetch` easily?

I wish vercel has default env var which has information on deployed environment or hostname but it seems that it does not have such a functionality so I am now stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could get env var for this ( VERCL_URL ). The document is here:

https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables/system-environment-variables